# React Native app crashes when trying to open camera

Tags: react-native

This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I have added:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

I have installed react-native-image-picker with npm i react-native-image-picker

the app crashes because it does not ask for permission, I just do not understand why it does not ask permission as I have already added the necessary information.

I am trying to get it to work on a ion emulator and my machine is M1 macbook.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the camera or accessing device storage, the app should be granted the required permission.

`react-native-permissions` provides permissions management abstracted API for both iOS and Android.

```js
import { request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS } from "react-native-permissions";

import { launchCamera } from "react-native-image-picker";

function capturePhoto() {
  request(
    Platform.OS === "ios" ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA
  ).then(async (result) => {
    if (result === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // Camera access permission granted, you can launch camera
      const result = await launchCamera();
    }
  });
}
```